# Matching blocks of text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have some text that looks like so,

```
PIN ABC
  DIRECTION IN;
  PORT
    RECT 10 20 20 40;
  END
END ABC

PIN ABC2
  DIRECTION OUT;
  PORT
    RECT 10 20 20 40;
  END
END ABC2
```

I need to extract the block of PIN definition that lives between PIN xxx and END xxx. I am trying to parse the text file with regex and I am not getting the desired result since I have nested END statement.

```
with open(f,'r') as fh:
    all = fh.read()
re.search('PIN(.*)END', all, re.DOTALL)
```

I really need to search for PIN xxx and END xxx as block markers

Is there a way

Comment: You can use [`^PIN (\S+).*?^END \1$`](https://regex101.com/r/haKC7c/1)

Comment: @anubhava `^PIN (\S+).*^END \1$` uses 15 fewer steps (greedy rather than lazy token)

Comment: @ctwheels There is no need counting the steps here, the real file may be much larger.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree, which means it should perform slightly better no?

Comment: @ctwheels Without knowing the actual contents, we cannot tell for sure which version will work more efficiently.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew very true. Just tested it myself. On the subset presented, however, it does perform better. But testing it on a larger subset, I've noticed the lazy token performs better. I've notified anubhava to include his original as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read file content in a single string then you can use this regex to match a text block from `PIN` to `END`:

```
^PIN (\S+).*^END \1$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/haKC7c/2/)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `PIN`: Match literal text `"PIN "`
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-space characters and capture it as group #1
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `^END`: Match `END` at line start
- `\1`: Back-reference to group #1
- `$`: End

Flags to be used are `MULTILINE` and `DOTALL`

---

PS: As cbwheels and Wiktor commented that use of a lazy quantifier in this regex i.e. `^PIN (\S+).*?^END \1$` may perform better if input text is large size.

Comment: Include your original regex as well (lazy token). It may perform better than the greedy token depending on input.